# Como pesquisar dados em qualquer coluna do datagridview, depois de popular ele pelo banco c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Tenho um datagridview que pega os dados do banco sqlserver e precisava fazer consultas, mas como são muitos dados não da para ficar puxando do banco.
queria fazer pesquisas através de um textbox com os dados que já estão no datagridview. tipo eu digito 'c' e aparece tudo que tem c, independente de qual coluna está. estou usando o windows form, trazendo os dados por camadas.
pego no banco os dados assim:

```
public class ConsultarSaida
{
    public SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    public DataTable TabelaEntrada = new DataTable();

    public void GetData(SaidasDTO dados)
    {
       // EntradaDTO Informacoes = new EntradaDTO();

        try
        {
            // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a 
            // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample
            // database accessible to your system.
            string sql = "select vi.prestador_id,vi.tipo,vi.img3,pres.nome,pres.cpf,pres.rg from visita vi inner join prestador pres on pres.id = vi.prestador_id where vi.condominio_id = '" + Informacoes.Condominio_id + "' and vi.datahora_saida is null order by vi.id asc";


            // Create a new data adapter based on the specified query.
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conexao.obterConexao());

            // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
            // update the database.
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);



            TabelaEntrada.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(TabelaEntrada);

        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            dados.mensagens = "Erro - Cliente " + e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

e no form assim:

```
 public void ConsultaVisita()
    {
        SaidasDTO dados = new SaidasDTO();
        ConsultarSaida consultarsaidas = new ConsultarSaida();

        //Chamar o método para gravar os dados acima
        consultarsaidas.GetData(dados);
        //consultarclientes.
        dgvSaida.Rows.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow linha in consultarsaidas.TabelaEntrada.Rows)
        {

            dgvSaida.Rows.Add(linha.ItemArray);
         }

        if (dgvSaida.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = dgvSaida.SelectedRows[0].Index;

            if (index >= 0)
                dgvSaida.Rows[index].Selected = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pode filtrar as linhas usando o linhas.ItemArray , converte  o array em  string (string.Join(",", arr);) de depois só adiciona a linhas que a string  contém a chave de que está a procura.

Answer (score 0):

Gustavo, eu mudaria a forma que você trabalha em dois pontos:

Em primeiro lugar, mude a forma que você trabalha com o grid, não adicione as linhas manualmente, use o DataSource do DataGridView para que seja populado:

```
dgvSaida.DataSource = dados;
```

E em segundo, para fazer o filtro coloque a sua propriedade `SaidasDTO dados = new SaidasDTO();` global para o formulário (declare ela fora do método) com isso você pode utilizar o linq para fazer o filtro e depois atualize o grid, exemplo:

```
//--- Você pode fazer também no KeyPress de um TextBox por exemplo
private void BotaoProcurar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //---- Não conheço seu modelo, então essa parte do Where você trabalha da forma que quiser
     // essa parte você altera: "x.Nome.Contais(textBox.text)"
     var dadosFiltrados = dados.Where(x=>x.Nome.Contais(textBox.Text)).ToList();
     dgvSaida.DataSource = null;
     dgvSaida.DataSource = dadosFiltrados;
}
```

Desse forma você será capaz de pesquisar por dados em memória. 
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: o problema é que já defini o nome de cada coluna e deixei algumas invisíveis, usando  dgvSaida.DataSource = dados; ele pega o nome da coluna da consulta e deixa visível campos que n serão necessários naquele momento